# How to set max users to 17.000

Tags: php, database, users, mysql

For a website i need a range of user_id's from 10.000 to 17.000
I've already been able to set the minimum, but i'm clueless as how to set the maximum. I've been Googling around for a while now, hoping it was just a simple MySQL statement. Can i set the max. user_id in the database, or is there a better/easier way to do this?

Any help on the matter would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your way around MySQL you can [create a trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html) that runs before INSERT and checks if new value is higher than 17000 and throws an error if it is.